# Remofi - Your Own PowerPoint Controller for Mobile Devices cannot run in fullscreen mode. It uses C#.

Tags: c#, android, jquery-mobile

Does anyone had try Remofi - Your Own PowerPoint Controller for Mobile Devices? I found this at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/240692/Remofi-Your-Own-PowerPoint-Controller-for-Mobile-D. The author said that the the source code given cannot run the powerpoint in fullscreen mode. I am making an android app that can both act as an Microphone and powerpoint controller. I just link[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRdhz.jpg) . The user just need to type in the IP address shown by the server and click connect powerpoint or speaker.

The blank space will display the two button up and down for controlling the powerpoint. The problem is that, control from the client browser would always force the PowerPoint to roll back to its preview mode.

Hope someone can help me.